# What New York building does Spider-Man glide through in Far From Home?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, film-location, spider-man-far-from-home

At the end of Far From Home, Peter is shown swinging through New York and, wearing the gliding suit he got from Tony Stark, glides towards a building that seems to have a completely open centre such that he's able to glide straight through it:

[image]

Is this a real building in New York or completely CGI? If it is real, what building is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No comment on what the building is "in-universe" — I assume the other answerer is right about that — but "out-of-universe," yes, that hole is computer-generated. In real life, the building in that position above Grand Central Station is the [MetLife Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetLife_Building), which is about that size and roughly that coloration but definitely doesn't have a big hole in the middle.

Here's a still from the movie (sorry for the YouTube quality), versus Google Streetview's view of the actual MetLife Building:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great catch, I've replaced the YouTube still with one from the movie.

Comment: Not sure why, but the jpg works for me where I am, while the png does not

Answer (score 9):

### Probably CGI

This is, in fact, a re-designed Avengers Tower that Tony Stark sold in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.

Since the old Avengers Tower was CGI, it's likely that this new building is also CGI.

> At the end of Spider-Man: Far From Home, Spider-Man swings past (and through) the redesigned building, giving audiences a glimpse at what it has now become. The most notable change that is visible is a gaping hole in the center. This is by design and not a result of another giant fight in New York. The gap is used as a lounge and garden area for the building, which has a modern, hi-tech feel to it. Beyond this, it isn't clear what the functionality of the hole is, other than giving Spider-Man the ability to swing through the building instead of around it.
>
> The new look makes the towering structure stand out even more than it did before, but Spider-Man: Far From Home stops short of showing us who is in the building or what name/company is branded on it.
>
> [Source](https://screenrant.com/spiderman-far-home-avengers-tower-owner-oscorp-baxter/)